# Cannot unregister functions from atexit in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection, atexit

First, I wrote a recording class with a flush method:

```
class Recorder
    def __init__(self, buffer_size, path):
        self._big_buffer = np.array(*buffer_size)
        self._path = path
    def push(self, data):
        # insert in self._big_buffer
        # if self._big_buffer is full:
        #     self._flush()
    def flush(self):
        # write buffer to disk (self._path)
```

Then, I wanted to flush at exit: when manually stopped, crashed or whatever reason.

So I used:

```
def __init__(self):
    (...)
    atexit.register(self.flush)
```

And it worked pretty well.

But now, I want to record, stop recording, record again, multiple times, with a different buffer size and to a different path. So I have to discard, then instanciate several `Recorder`. It kind of works, but older `Recorder`'s memory (containing some fat `self._big_buffer̀`) is not freed since it's retained by `atexit`. Even when I explicitly call `del`.
I can't `atexit.unregister(self._flush)` since it's Python 3 only.

I would prefer not to reuse existing instances, but discarding older instances and create new ones.

How would you handle such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a weak reference to the `atexit` handler, so the object
won't be retained if it is deleted elsewhere:

```
import atexit
import weakref

class CallableMethodWeakRef:
    def __init__(self, object, method_name):
        self.object_ref = weakref.ref(object)
        self.method_name = method_name
    def __call__(self):
        object = self.object_ref()
        if object:
            getattr(object, self.method_name)()

class Recorder:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        atexit.register(CallableMethodWeakRef(self, 'flush'))

    def flush(self):
        print 'flushing'
```

The method is passed as a string in order to avoid a lot of problems with
bound method weak references, if you find it disturbing you can always use
a `BoundMethodWeakref` implementation like this one: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578298-bound-method-weakref/

Comment: Note: the registered `CallableMethodWeakRef` objects will be called, even if
the underlying object has been deleted. It doesn't really matter, except if you have a huge number of `Recorder` objects - in this case, you can combine
the technique described here with a custom `atexit.unregister` method of your own, I can give you some hints

Comment: I tried your recipe with the method passed as a string and it's working great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you're trying to use the wrong tool. The `with` statement and context managers are a very good tool for this. File IO is the main example that most python users will get introduced to the with statement.

```
f = open("somefile.txt", "w")
try:
    f.write("...")
    # more file operations
finally:
    # regardless of what happens, make sure the files is closed 
    f.close()
```

Becomes:

```
with open("somefile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("...")
    # more file operations
# close automatically called at the end of the block
```

You can create your own context managers by writing `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods for your class.

```
class Recorder
    def __init__(self, buffer_size, path):
        self._big_buffer = np.array(*buffer_size)
        self._path = path
    def push(self, data):
        # insert in self._big_buffer
        # if self._big_buffer is full:
        #     self._flush()
    def flush(self):
        # write buffer to disk (self._path)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exctype, exception, traceback):
        # If an exception was thrown in the with block you will get the details here. 
        # If you want the say that the exception has been handled and for it not to be 
        # raised outside the with block then return True
        self.flush()
        # self.close() ?
```

You would then use your `Recorder` object like:

```
with Recorder(...) as recorder:
    # operations with recorder
    ...
# regardless of what happens the recorder will be flushed at this point
```

Comment: Well, I do know about with statement. It's just I cannot use it because of the way the app is built right now. Or maybe I could still use it but 1/ the code will be a lot uglier, 2/ it would be easy to forget to use `with`. Still, +1 for a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely the answer *is* to allow your `Recorder` to change paths and buffer characteristics at will. You say *"I would prefer not to reuse existing instances, but discarding older instances and create new ones."* but you don't give any rationale for that,
except perhaps your assumption that the *"older Recorder's memory (containing some fat `self._big_buffer̀`) is not freed since it's retained by `atexit`"*, which I believe is incorrect.

While it is true that `atexit` retains a reference to the recorder object, this will only mean that the buffer memory is retained as long as the recorder refers to it. It would be quite easy to add a `close()` method such as

```
    def close(self):
        self.flush()
        self._big_buffer = None
```

and bingo! No reference to the buffer memory exists, and it is collectable.

Your `__init__()` method should simply register with `atexit`, then the `open()` method (which does the rest of what `__init__()` currently does) can be used multiple times, each one followed by a `close()` call.

In summary, I think your problem cries out for a single object.

Comment: The answer from @Dunes represents a more general approach to the problem, though I suspect there _may_ be rare cases where `atexit` traps circumstances that the `__exit__` method of a context manager may not.

Comment: The problem, in my case, for a single object, is I intend to use simultany, more than one instance of the class in a near future. The atexit mechanism is merely here to flush before a crash or a way to quit the app which is not handled (it uses pyqt by the way)

Comment: There's absolutely no reason I can think of why you shouldn't have as many instances as you like. While it's true that the `atexit` calls will retain references to them, as long as you call their `close()` method first that won't be unduly expensive, since no buffer references will be retained. Just make sure the `flush()` method call returns immediately if the buffer is `None` so's not to cause problems on exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the handle by hand from the (undocumented) `atexit._exithandlers` list.

```
import atexit

def unregister(func, *targs, **kargs):

    """unregister a function previously registered with atexit.
       use exactly the same aguments used for before register.
    """
    for i in range(0,len(atexit._exithandlers)):
        if (func, targs, kargs) == atexit._exithandlers[i] :
            del atexit._exithandlers[i]
            return True
    return False
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: leading underscore in `_exithandlers` is there for purpose, given solution looks like a hack, which abuses [non-documented behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)

Comment: If you want to be polite, you can create my_atexit just based in atexit code and do the same as your own extension. ;)

Comment: Please, your link is for py3 and this topic is for py2.